# Scriptaculous slider price range handles

Tags: slider, range, scriptaculous, handles

I'm using Scriptaculous to create a price range slider with two handles.
Problem at the moment is the two handles can slide past each other. How can I make them stop if they reach the other handle

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [`restricted`](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/slider/) option to `true`:

> Used only for multiple handles, when restricted is true, handle(s) with greater indexes are not allowed to have values less than handles with smaller indexes. When restricted is false, handles can be moved independently from others.